# XFCE login screen: All passwords are correct

Tags: linux, login, xfce, xubuntu

Everytime I boot my computer or just log out, the random password I enter in the XFCE login screen, is correct (even when it's not). I'm running XUbuntu 14.04.

I also have a second machine running the exact same version of XUbuntu with almost the same settings, but on that one it works fine.

How do I fix this? Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to Xfce, but to lightdm (or whatever desktop manager Xubuntu is using). The desktop manager uses PAM for authentication. PAM does several things, but in the end it checks your`/etc/shadow`for the valid password. See http://linux.die.net/man/5/shadow how to interpret this file. And only use`vipw -s`for editing this file.